# Loop through json in php foreach breakss off after 5 passes

Tags: php, json

i have the following code:

```
echo $response ."<br>";
$yummy=(json_decode($response));

$index_temp=0;

foreach ($yummy as $optie ) {

    echo "TEMP = " . $yummy->measures[$index_temp]->value . "<br>";
    $index_temp=$index_temp+2;

}
```

the array with the output is:

```
{"id":"datalog_transmission","firmwareType":"SenlabH","measures":[{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565756178419,"value":14.8125},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565756178419,"value":89},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565756778419,"value":14.6875},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565756778419,"value":89},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565757378419,"value":14.625},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565757378419,"value":90},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565757978419,"value":14.625},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565757978419,"value":90},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565758578419,"value":14.6875},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565758578419,"value":90},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565759178419,"value":14.6875},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565759178419,"value":90},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565759778419,"value":14.4375},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565759778419,"value":90},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565760378419,"value":14.375},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565760378419,"value":87},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565760978419,"value":14.1875},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565760978419,"value":88},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565761578419,"value":14.3125},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565761578419,"value":88},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565762178419,"value":14.5625},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565762178419,"value":86},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565762778419,"value":14.75},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565762778419,"value":83},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565763378419,"value":14.875},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565763378419,"value":81},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565763978419,"value":14.9375},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565763978419,"value":81},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565764578419,"value":15.125},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565764578419,"value":79},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565765178419,"value":15.4375},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565765178419,"value":78},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565765778419,"value":15.6875},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565765778419,"value":78},{"id":"temperature","timestamp":1565766378419,"value":15.8125},{"id":"humidity","timestamp":1565766378419,"value":76},{"id":"battery_current_level","timestamp":1565766686419,"value":98}],"parameters":[],"events":[]}
TEMP = 14.8125
TEMP = 14.6875
TEMP = 14.625
TEMP = 14.625
TEMP = 14.6875
```

the problem is, that the foreach loop always breaks off after 5 passes.

Does anyone know where the problem is?

thank you,
markus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping the outer array (id, firmwareType, etc...) which only contains 5 items. It seems like you want to loop the measures property (`$yummy->measures`):

```
foreach ($yummy->measures as $optie ) {
    echo "TEMP = " . $optie->value . "<br>";
}
```

Which will produce the following output:

```
TEMP = 14.8125
TEMP = 89
TEMP = 14.6875
TEMP = 89
TEMP = 14.625
TEMP = 90
...
```

As per your comment, to output the 2 id's differently, you can do something like:

```
foreach ($yummy->measures as $optie ) {
    if ($optie->id === "temperature"){
        echo "TEMP = " . $optie->value . "<br>";
    }

    if ($optie->id === "humidity"){
        echo "HUM = " . $optie->value . "<br>";
    }
}
```

Which will give you:

```
TEMP = 14.8125
HUM = 89
TEMP = 14.6875
HUM = 89
TEMP = 14.625
HUM = 90
...
```

Comment: ok thank you, works perfect. last question: how can i read out the timestamp for each? this does not work

```
           if ($optie->id === "timestamp"){
                $DATE1= $optie->value;
             }
```

Comment: @MarkusDuschek that should work fine. What do you expect to happen with `$DATE1`?

Comment: ok thank you for your help.

now i have another problem

now i want so write each set (temperature, timestamp, humiditiy) in a file:

```
file_put_contents('pusherlog1.txt', $TEMP1." Grad Celsius ". $HUM1." Prozent Luftfeuchte "."RAWDATA: ".$RAWDATA1. " FPort: ".$FPORT1 ." Uhrzeit: " .$DATE1 ." DEVEUI1: " .$DEVEUI1." BAT: ".$BAT1 ."\r\n" , FILE_APPEND);

```

Comment: @MarkusDuschek make a new question for that. If my post has solved you problem please accept (the tick/check)